# $\tau(n) \le 2\sqrt n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to show $\forall n \in \Bbb N$  $$\tau(n) \le 2\sqrt n $$

$\tau $ is number of all of positive divisor of $n$

Comment: How many divisors $d|n$ can there be with $d>\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Also, $$  \tau(n) \leq 24 \;\left( \frac{n}{315} \right)^{1/3}  $$ and $$ \tau(n) \leq n^{\left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right)}   $$ with equality in the latter inequality only at $n = 6,983,776,800,$ with $\tau(n) = 2304$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $d$ is a positive divisor of $n$, then $e = n/d$ is also a positive divisor of $n$. Now one of $d, e$ is $\le \sqrt{n}$. (Possibly both, but only when $d = e = \sqrt{n}$, that is, $n$ is a square.) So the pairs $(d, e)$ such that $d e = n$ are at most $\sqrt{n}$. Hence the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If $n = ab$ with $a \leq b$, then $a \leq \sqrt n $ and $b \geq \sqrt n$. So you can not have more than $2\sqrt n $ divisors of $n$.